# scalable circular svg mask

Tags: html, css, svg, mask

I am trying to create a css class which would mask a square div or other square element so that you would only see a circle with the given content in the div. I want the circle to completely fill the div so that the four sides are tangent. The trick is the only given is the fact that the div or element is square because the element needs to remain scalable. For example: the element height and with might both be 50% not 50px. I also am trying to make the div centered on the page which is proving quite challenging as well.

Here's the code I've been working on:

```
.circlemask{
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-top:auto;
 margin-bottom:auto;
 mask: url("img/circle.svg");
 -webkit-mask-box-image: url("img/circle.svg");
 -webkit-mask-size: 100% 100%;
} 

<div class="circlemask" height="70% width="70%"></div>
```

The code includes a link to a circle.svg file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <mask id="c1" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <circle id="circle" cx="240" cy="135" r="135" fill="white"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#circle"/>
</svg>
```

I imagine there is probably a way to do this without the separate svg file however.

If you have and suggestions/answers I would love to hear them.
If this proves impossible I'd like to hear any other approaches.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain why you're using mask versus clip-path, and image mask versus a mask element?  Or for that matter, just using border-radius to crop to a circle? Unfortunately, mask support is rather inconsistent right now.  You should be able to create a scaling mask with `objectBoundingBox` units (see [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/v5nepqp9/)), but in reality the new CSS Masking spec has so confused implementations that even applying masks to SVG content is getting unreliable cross-browser.

Comment: I know literally nothing about html/css. If there is some way to do this with javascript or some other work around I would be totally game to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is just with `border-radius`.

```
.circlemask {
   border-radius: 50%;
}
```

No need to use an SVG.

Comment: You will need to specify a specific size, eg. `width: 400px; height: 400px;` to ensure a square. See: http://jsfiddle.net/6y2jrb9r/